# Transfer field data from Contract to Custom object field

Tags: apex, trigger

I want to transfer some of the field data from Contract to Service TimeCard (Custom object) field.

The same field in both the object. Once the contract is created and under that when the service timecard record is generated the (Daily rate and Daily rate offset) data will automatically transfer from Contract to my custom object field.

I had applied the below code.

```
trigger servicecontract on Contract (after insert) {  

list<SFDC_Service_Timecard__c> memberInsertList = new list<SFDC_Service_Timecard__c>();

for (Contract cont : Trigger.new) {

    SFDC_Service_Timecard__c stc = new SFDC_Service_Timecard__c();    

    stc.Daily_Rate__c = cont.Daily_Rate__c;
    stc.Offsite_Daily_Rate__c = cont.Daily_Rate_Offsite__c;

    memberInsertList.add(stc);      
}    
insert memberInsertList;
```

}

Comment: Your code violates the basic rules of bulkification, but is there a specific question you had in mind?

Comment: and ..use of variable named `member` to mean a `Contract` Sobject in the top part of your code and then a `SFDC_Service_timecard__c` in the bottom part of your code will lead to confusion by either you or the next person maintaining this. Also Set variable `Ids` is at best, ambiguous

Comment: i had 2 fields (Deal Total and Deal Rate Offsite) in both  the object. Once contract will create (Deal Total = Total1 + Total2) and ) Deal RateOffsite = Amt1 + Amt2). In the custom object (ServiceTimeCard - i had same field (Deal Total and Deal Rate Offsite) whenever new Servicetime card will create the value will pass from Contract Field to Servicetime card record. Remember for 1 contract we can create multiple servicetime card. So for Contract1 - Service timecard1 , Servicetimecard2 .